# typescript types with Promise

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm still relatively new to typescript and I cannot figure out how to add types to a function that use a Promise.

I follow the suggestion from Typescript and make my function Props from `UserStateProps` to `Promise<UserStateProps>` but now is complaining that this `Promise<UserStateProps>` is missing the necessary properties.

I have this function:

```
    const mergeCookiesWithUserState = async (defaultUserState: UserStateProps): Promise<UserStateProps>  => {
  const newUserState = { ...defaultUserState }

  for (const key in newUserState) {
    if (Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(cookiesName, key)) {
      const cookieValue = await getCookieValue(cookiesName[key])

      console.log({ cookieValue})
      if (cookieValue !== undefined) {
        newUserState[key] = cookieValue
      }
    }
  }
    
  return newUserState
}
```

which I use to update the React state.
The react user state uses UserStateProps to check the state types.
Since when I introduced a Promise in the `mergeCookiesWithUserState`, the user state complained about its props:

`Type 'Promise<UserStateProps>' is missing the following properties from type 'UserStateProps': numOfSearches, language, adultContentFilter, openInNewTab, isModalOpents(2739)`

These are the interface:

```
export interface UserStateProps {
 

 numOfSearches: number
  language: number
  adultContentFilter: number
  openInNewTab: boolean
  isModalOpen: boolean
}
export interface UserContextProps {
  userState: UserStateProps
  setUserState: (userState: Partial<UserStateProps>) => void
}
```

Anyone can help me out to understand this thing?

UPDATE:
it turned out that the problem was how I have written `getCookieValue()` and therefore how to handle the returned Promised from it.
But all your comments put me on the right track again to figure out the solution.
I believe the answer I sign as correct, is the most pertinent one for the error I got and the async nature of my problem.
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what your surrounding code is, but the error is most likely, that you are trying to assign the promise instead of the promise result. You'll either have to use  `async` / `await` or set the state through `.then`

Comment: ^ wherever you're calling `mergeCookiesWithUserState`, use `await mergeCookiesWithUserState`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Type 'Promise<UserStateProps>' is missing the following properties from type 'UserStateProps'
```

That means that somewhere in your code you did:

```
const example: UserStateProps = mergeCookiesWithUserState()
```

Along with that you specifically told your function type to return `Promise<UserStateProps>` which you're trying to assign to `UserStateProps`.

You can't assign a promise to UserStateProps.

The promise is there because of the fact that your function is marked `async` which will automatically return a promise with whatever value it should return as the type of the promise, which it will eventually resolve to.

```
const example: UserStateProps = await mergeCookiesWithUserState()
```

That's all you need to fix your error, the `await` keyword will let the promise resolve before assigning the value to `example`.

Comment: Also, this needs to be in an async function or the environment needs top-level-await enabled. I added this to the answer.